# How would I sort through an array of structs?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

I have a struct containing song data:

```
public struct uLib
    {
        public string Path;
        public string Artist;
        public string Title;
        public string Album;
        public string Length;
    }
```

My library consists of an array of this `uLib`.  How would I sort this array by say Artist?  Is there a native sort function I can call on this type of array, or will I have to "roll my own"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, that should not be a struct. It's larger than 16 bytes, so you don't get the performance benefits of having a struct. Also, it doesn't represent a single value, so it doesn't make sense semantically to make it a struct. Just make it a class instead.

The `Array` class has a `Sort` method that you can use:

```
Array.Sort(theArray, (x,y) => string.Compare(x.Artist,y.Artist));
```

If you don't have C# 3 you use a delegate instead of the lambda expression:

```
Array.Sort(theArray, delegate(uLib x, uLib y) { return string.Compare(x.Artist,y.Artist) } );
```

Edit:
Here's an example of what your data could look like as a class:

```
public class ULib {

    private string _path, _artist, _title, _album, _length;

    public string Path { get { return _path; } set { _path = value; } }
    public string Artist { get { return _artist; } set { _artist = value; } }
    public string Title { get { return _title; } set { _title = value; } }
    public string Album { get { return _album; } set { _album = value; } }
    public string Length { get { return _length; } set { _length = value; } }

    public ULib() {}

    public ULib(string path, string artist, string title, string album, string length) {
       Path = path;
       Artist = artist;
       Title = title;
       Album = album;
       Length = length;
    }

}
```

In C# there there is a short form for a property. Instead of writing code for a private variable and a setter and getter to access it, this creates that automatically:

```
public string Path { get; set; }
```

Comment: That works great.  Thanks.  You say I shouldn't use a struct, how would you organize this kind of data?

Comment: Put it in the class - and use properties instead of public fields, too.

Comment: Guffa - Thanks for clarifying.  Would that get sorted the same way?

Comment: Yes, only slightly faster as there is 80% less data to move around. :)

Comment: @Guffa: would you mind to provide the source of your claim that 
 larger than 16 bytes => no perf gain? thanks

Comment: @pointernil: For example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082311/why-should-a-net-struct-be-less-than-16-bytes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407691/c-struct-design-why-16-byte-is-recommended-size/2407706

Answer (score 1):

from u in ULibArray order by u.Artist select u;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `uLibs` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can try this:

```
uLibs.OrderBy(i => i.Artist)
```

This sorts the `uLib` instances by using a key; in this case, you've selected Artist to be the key to compare against. Similar sorting is possible against your other fields.

Comment: You'll lose the result if you do this, though. The correct way do do this is
var orderedLibs = uLibs.OrderBy(i => i.Artist)

Comment: Yes, this is meant to be included as part of another statement. What you do with the result is up to you, of course.