# how to implement inheritance between two Structs

Tags: c#, struct

Please, I want to implement inheritance between two Structs. Performance is highly important.

Sample code:

```
struct IntColl
{
}

struct ValidIntColl : IntColl
{
}
```

Message from Visual Studio:

`Error 1 Type 'IntColl' in interface list is not an interface`

How do I get this error? IntColl is a Struct, not an Interface!

Comment: Right there in the docs: "Structs can implement an interface but they cannot inherit from another struct."

Comment: You can't inherit with `struct`s

Comment: my brain hurts after reading this...

Comment: Are you sure you understand the pros and cons (in terms of performance) involved here?  I stand unconvinced.

Comment: Minor thought: I wonder if you actually want a `SomeStruct<int>`

Answer (score 4):

Structs can only implement interfaces, they can't inherit other structs.

For more information, please see these other questions:

- [Why a C# struct cannot be inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310103/why-a-c-sharp-struct-cannot-be-inherited)
- [Why don't structs support inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222935/why-dont-structs-support-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

[struct (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Structs can implement an interface but **they cannot inherit from another struct**.

So you simply can't inherit from `struct` to create another `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use composition, since inheritance won't work here:

```
struct IntColl
{
}

struct ValidIntColl
{
    IntColl MyIntCollField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have struct inheritance. You'll need to change them into classes. Speed shouldn't be impacted all that much.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a struct that inherits from another struct so it gets put on the stack

You cant:

> Structs can implement an interface but they cannot inherit from another struct.

per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Speed is of high importance

You are assuming that structs are slower than classes.  While there may be *some* speed difference, I would not make this assumption categorically.  What you are *doing* with the clases/structs is very likely to be slower than the memory access.

If inheritance is a key requirement, then you'll need to build your objects as classes rather than structs.  Or use another pattern like encapsulation (have one struct be a *property* of another).

If you get to the point that you can *prove* that classes will be slower that structs in your scenario, your only option may be to replicate the necessary fields in the structure map.