# C# Limitations of struct. Why are they sealed?

Tags: c#, .net, object, struct

I am having a bit of an issue grasping the concept of the struct and no one can answer my question.
I know it is "like" an object, you can have methods and fields.
What I do not understand is why they are sealed. Why is there a lack of inheritance and polymorphism
which limits their abilities. Is there really much real world use for a struct, I know they are smaller than 
an object, I just cannot find any real examples that help me understand the benefits.
Thanks.

Comment: See [Why a C# struct cannot be inherited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310103/), [Why are .NET value types sealed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769306/), [Inherit from struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408667/),  [Why don't structs support inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222935/), [Google: C# struct sealed site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+struct+sealed+site%3Astackoverflow.com). Please show some research effort. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because a `struct` ***is a value***; a struct that contains a `float` is exactly 4 bytes long. There is no object-header that indicates what the concrete type is: the thing that knows the type is the compiler (and the resulting IL) - the type information is not self-contained in the value. So, regular polymorphism cannot work. If you do:

```
MyType type = new MySubType(); // if this was a struct and if this compiled
```

then from the compiler's perspective, the type of that is `MyType`. There is no notion, after the assignment, that this is or ever was a `MySubType`. Indeed, you can use `unsafe` code to force the bits of one value-type into another.

Additionally, this same facet of structs means that you would not be able to add fields in sub-types: the size **has to be fixed**, which makes this impossible.

Basically, if you are thinking in terms of inheritance, you are using `struct`s incorrectly; actually, **most times** that I see people using `struct`s they are using them incorrectly. `struct`s should represent **values** (ideally immutable etc).

---

> Is there really much real world use for a struct

Yes; for representing values - a `ComplexNumber` type for example; and for some **highly optimized** scenarios where GC is prohibitive, but which only affects a small number of developers. [Here's one example of this](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html); another common example is "games", but: switching between `class` and `struct` is a **much** bigger change than changing the keyword. You need to know what you are doing, and why you are doing it.

What you should **not** do is things like:

```
// ***BAD CODE: DO NOT DO***
public struct Customer
{ // I don't need inheritance; a struct will be faster and smaller
  // yay me, I'm awesome

    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

The above is clearly best represented as a `class`. Also: properties.

> I know they are smaller than an object

In some ways, this is not true; for example, most useful `struct`s are larger than a reference - which can be problematic if you are passing super-sized `struct`s around on the stack without thinking what you are doing.

Comment: +1 "switching between class and struct is a much bigger change than changing the keyword". Coming from gamedev - could not agree more.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. **It is a value type and all value types are sealed**. Though you can inherit it from interface.

Comment: This doesn't address the "why" part of the question