# Why cannot derive from value types in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, types

I know that all value types are derived implicitly from the System.ValueType. and structs can implement interfaces, but I need to know why cannot derive from value types in C#.

Comment: Basically, value types are defined using structs.  There is no inheritance for structs.

Comment: @Jeff that just restates the question, though - it doesn't answer *why*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't structs support inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222935/why-dont-structs-support-inheritance)

Comment: @Marc: I know, that's why I didn't put it in as an answer.  I couldn't really come up with a good enough explanation at the moment.  ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, value-types have no object header (because they aren't objects), so there would be no way to identify the *actual* type, or to do virtual dispatch.

Secondly - how could you add fields to sub types? The size has to be known by the compiler (for stack space etc), so:

```
Foo foo = ...
```

must always take the same amount of space.

Likewise, an abstract base-type wouldn't work, as you can ***always*** construct a struct.

Basically, they would be horrible malformed things, crippled and ugly.

I find it interesting that you would *want* a subtype of a value - that sounds a bit like a confused usage of a struct.

Comment: "horrible
malformed things, crippled and ugly". Like in C++?!

Comment: @David it has been over a decade since I touched C++, so my memory is vague - but: probably :)

Comment: I can imagine usage cases for struct inheritance, subject to the following constraints: (1) the derived type couldn't add fields, but it could add or shadow properties or methods; (2) implicit widening conversions would exist among all struct types derived from the same base, and such conversions would behave as a "reinterpret cast"; additionally, a derived struct could be passed as a "ref" parameter to a routine expecting a related one (3) for purposes of generics and boxing, the struct types would be recognized as different types by the type system.

Comment: I sometimes find myself wanting no more data than a single primitive type but wanting to give it a useful-for-identification name and methods/operators. Ex: Bitmask : int.