# Know when variables inside a struct become null in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a struct on the server-side with a layout like this:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; };
    public string SomeString1;
    public string SomeString2;
    public string SomeString3;
}
```

I am using a client/server model, and an instance of this struct gets referenced a lot of times as it has really important information (over 200 times).

The thing is that when some function gets called, the values inside this struct become null. I don't know why and it is been bugging me for a really long time.

I call a lot of methods before realizing that this values are null, so I don't know which section of my code nullify my strings.

I am using VS2012, but I have 2010 and 2008 ultimate as well. I was wondering if there is a way to perform a trigger when some section of code nullifies my strings.

I tried to add some properties like this, bot the exception was never thrown:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    string somestr;
    public string SomeString
    {
        get { return somestr; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("stirng is null");
            }

            somestr = value;
        }
    }
    public string SomeString1;
    public string SomeString2;
    public string SomeString3;
}
```

Might not be important, but this is one of the structs I am using (the Name variable becomes null in some part of my code, and the rest turns into default()):

```
[ProtoContract]
public struct CharacterInformation
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public IntegerVector2 Position;
    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public CharacterDirection Direction;
    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public CharacterStatus Status;
    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public CharacterClass Class;
    [ProtoMember(8)]
    public CharacterRace Race;
    [ProtoMember(9)]
    public CharacterType Type;
    [ProtoMember(10)]
    public CharacterFaction Faction;
    [ProtoMember(11)]
    public float MovementModifier;
    [ProtoMember(12)]
    public CharacterEquipment Equipment;
}
```

**Edit:** The only instance of this struct is created on a Sql-related function:

```
public CharacterServerInformation GetInformation(int charID)
        {
            CharacterServerInformation information = new CharacterServerInformation();
            if (!authInstance.CharacterExists(charID))
            {
                // char doesn't exists
                throw new Exception("Character doesn't exists");
            }
            information.ID = charID;
            information.Experience = GetExperience(charID);
            information.Info.Direction = CharacterDirection.Bottom;
            information.Info.Name = authInstance.CharacterGetName(charID);
            information.Info.Class = GetClass(charID);
            information.Info.Faction = GetFaction(charID);
            information.Info.Position = GetPosition(charID);
            information.Info.Race = GetRace(charID);
            information.Info.Status = GetStatus(charID);
            information.Info.Type = GetType(charID);
            information.Info.MovementModifier = 1f; // should store old movement modifier, but well, whatever
            information.HealthLeft = GetHealthLastLogout(charID);
            return information;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are creating and using instances of the struct?

Comment: Simple debug version:  throw `ArgumentException` if something happens to set it to null?  I haven't done much with C# (yet), but isn't modifying internal struct values recommended against?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - yes..OP should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: Should I change all my structs to classes? If they have mutable data*

Comment: @Pacha - this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c may help answer your question about struct vs. class.

Comment: @Pacha I think so. For performance issues and bug-prevention (since structs are passed by value not by reference)

Comment: You might be right. I am really new to programming, I still make silly mistakes. Didn't know about this. I thought that structs should contain data and classes functionality.

Comment: Putting code to notify if a setter is called with a null value might not help.  The struct may be getting nullified because you're assigning `_s = new SomeStruct();` somewhere by mistake.  The property setters won't get called here, but the underlying fields will be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is purely because you're using `struct` and not making a `class`.  Since `struct` members are copied by value into methods and when returned from methods, including property getters, it's likely that you're "losing" the information by accidentally writing a new `struct` somewhere.

In this case, `class` seems is far more appropriate.  If you read [Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229017%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you'll see that `struct` should only be used when:

- It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
- It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
- It is immutable.
- It will not have to be boxed frequently.

In your case, all of these criteria ( except maybe the last) are being violated, so `class` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Out of curiosity why the smaller than 16 bytes recommendation?  Why not 32 for example?

Comment: @Jared Very good reason why 16 bytes was choosen.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2437938/65358