# Interfaces vs disciminated union for SVG curves

Tags: c#

For one of the preprocessing steps of a GPU renderer for Scalable Vector Graphics, I am dealing with SVG curves (of the four types: lines, quadratic and cubic Bézier curves, and ellipse arcs). One of the steps is curve subdivision on intersections, as a prestep algorithm to populate a doubly-connected edge list.

Previously, I went to store each type of curve in a separate struct (`Line`, `QuadraticBezier`, `CubicBezier` and `EllipticArc`), which means that, to operate on them, I needed to write the same (similar) code to each of those combinations (leading to a whopping 10-ication of the code). Now, I want to try something different. I have two options: using an interface `ICurve`, or use a `struct Curve` that has a `Type` and reunite all the operations.

The code that operates on the curve looks (bar the duplication) like this:

```
// Reunite all the shapes
var curves = new List<ICurve>(path.PathCommands.Length);

foreach (var cmd in path.PathCommands)
    /* generate the curves by evaluating the path commands */;

// Reunite all intersections to subdivide the curves
var curveRootSets = new SortedSet<float>[curves.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < curveRootSets.Length; i++)
    curveRootSets[i] = new SortedSet<float>(new[] { 1f }, Half.Comparer);

// Get all intersections
for (int i = 0; i < curves.Count; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; i < curves.Count; j++)
        foreach (var pair in CurveIntersectionPairs(curves[i], curves[j]))
        {
            curveRootSets[i].Add(pair.A);
            curveRootSets[j].Add(pair.B);
        }

// Account for possibly-duplicate curves
foreach (var set in curveRootSets) set.Remove(0f);

// Subdivide the curves
var curvesSubdiv = curves.Zip(curveRootSets, delegate (ICurve curve, SortedSet<float> set)
{
    float v = 0f;
    var list = new List<ICurve>();
    foreach (var l in set)
    {
        list.Add(curve.Subcurve(v, l));
        v = l;
    }
    return list;
}).Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<ICurve>(), Enumerable.Concat);
```

The first approach I have come to is to define an `interface ICurve` with the necessary contract to allow it to work both on the subdivision phase and on the DCEL phase. The interface looks like this:

```
public interface ICurve
{
    // Evaluates the curve at parameter "t"
    Vector2 At(float t);

    // The derivative of the curve (aka the "velocity curve")
    ICurve Derivative { get; }

    // Gets the curve that maps [0,1] to [l,r] on this curve
    ICurve Subcurve(float l, float r);

    // The bounding box of the curve
    FRectangle BoundingBox { get; }

    // The measure of how much counterclockwise the curve is
    // (aka double the area swept by it and the segments that
    // connect the endpoints to the origin)
    float Winding { get; }

    // Does the curve degenerate to a single point?
    bool IsDegenerate { get; }
}
```

And then I would have each struct to implement the interface:

```
public struct Line : ICurve { /* ... */ }
public struct QuadraticBezier : ICurve { /* ... */ }
public struct CubicBezier : ICurve { /* ... */ }
public struct EllipticArc : ICurve { /* ... */ }
```

This works wonders, and each of the classes correctly implements the contract methods, and thus I can work with `ICurves` abstractly, and even implement more curves as the SVG specification asks for them. But I have read some horror stories about boxing/unboxing of interfaces (since they are reference types) and the structs allocated on the heap, which would be scattered on the memory. I guess I could get better (on cache coherency, indirection and other means) by setting up a `struct Curve` with a `public readonly CurveType Type` and all the necessary fields for it:

```
public enum CurveType { Line, QuadraticBezier, CubicBezier, EllipticArc }

public partial struct Curve
{
    // four Vector2's are sufficient for now
    readonly Vector2 A, B, C, D;

    public readonly CurveType Type;

    // Evaluates the curve at parameter "t"
    public Vector2 At(float t)
    {
        // "Dispatch" the function based on the type
        switch (Type)
        {
            case CurveType.Line: return LineAt(t);
            case CurveType.QuadraticBezier: return QuadraticBezierAt(t);
            case CurveType.CubicBezier: return CubicBezierAt(t);
            case CurveType.EllipticArc: return EllipticArcAt(t);
            default: return new Vector2(float.NaN, float.NaN);
        }
    }

    // Other contract methods implemented similarly ...
}
```

Since `struct`s are value types, I can allocate them locally using `List<Curve>` (which uses an array internally) and benefit (at least a little) from cache locality. However, I would lose the ability of "open inheritance" (I think that is a non-issue, because there is only a handful of curves in use on today's SVG).

But maybe I am overengineering it? I am a newcomer to C# (been to C++ for some years), and I do not know the intricacies an interface would bring to value types, and maybe a dynamic dispatch provided by an interface would be faster than a "manual dispatch". Because of this, I would like to ask for your knowledge on those specific approaches. Maybe there is another, better alternative I am not aware?

Bear in mind I am preparing this to work on real-world SVG files, which means potentially tens or hundreds of curves per path, and having to subdivide them afterwards. I could reuse those constructions when I come to generate the primitives encompassing each curve, assign fills and other nuances of the SVG.

Comment: if you seek performances, use fixed size array instead of List<>, no foreach but regular for. avoid linq and makes instead array copies. does your struct size exceed 16 bytes?? if yes, you'll loose stacking advantages. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082311/why-should-a-net-struct-be-less-than-16-bytes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is trying to leverage type variance with value types. That is a big no, no in c#; you can’t do it. There sadly is no way to have a `List<T>` where `T` is a struct that can admit all your different value types. Type variance in c# must preserve identity and that is, by definition, incompatible with value types.

The obvious first option is what you’ve already figured out: `ICurve` but that runs into boxing penalties that can be prohibitly expensive.

A second option is actually making your curves reference types but that probably puts a whole lot of collection pressure on the GC.

The third option is implementing a single struct `Curve` and on creation define the type it really is a part of its state. This is probably the better option and you’ve already identified this as a viable one.

Comment: Sometimes I miss the union and memory management capabilities of C++. The best way would be an `union` with all the types.

Comment: I guess I stated your third option on my post. `struct Curve` and `enum CurveType`.

Comment: @JoaoBapt yes, and it seems to be the best option but testing is actually the way to really find out. #2 is an option and only testing will tell you if collection pressure is a problem or not.