# Static factory method - Separate Class to hold data in a list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, extension-methods

I have this class I'm using to create a list of values

```
public class map
{
    private static List<map> mapValues = new List<map>();
    public static IEnumerable<map> AllInstances
    {
        get { return mapValues; }
    }

    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public Object theobject { get; set; }

    private map()   // Private ctor ensures only a member
    {               // function can create a new map
    }
    public static map Create()
    {
        var mv = new map();
        mapValues.Add(mv);
        return mv;
    }

    public static void Delete(map itemToRemove)
    {
        mapValues.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
}
```

I have based this class from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8847810/5629895)

But when I come to the part of `var Foundit = MyData.AllInstances.FirstOrDefault(md => md.Device == "blah");`
`Myclass` does not have this `FirstOrDefault`.

The idea with this list is to have a grid/map-like system for placing objects in a WPF canvas.

What am I missing to get this working?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` is an [`IEnumerable` extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You need to import the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an extension method, so try adding this namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Another point:** As far as the `AllInstances` is a static class member, you do not have to call it from a `map` instance like `MyData`, simply you can call it from the class like this:

```
map.AllInstances  //access AllInstances through the class name
```

Comment: Thank you, i can now use it as the other comment showed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file where you want to use `.FirstOrDefault(...)`.