# How to use Array.sort to sort an array of structs, by a specific element

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Simple, I have a struct like this:

```
struct bla{
  string name;
  float depth;
}
```

I have an bla array, and I want to sort by depth, being the greatest depth first.
What should the delegate do/return? I cant find any concrete example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y1008) which takes a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
bla[] blas = new[] { 
    new bla() { name = "3", depth = 3 }, 
    new bla() { name = "4", depth = 4 }, 
    new bla() { name = "2", depth = 2 }, 
    new bla() { name = "1", depth = 1 }, 
};

Array.Sort<bla>(blas, (x,y) => x.depth.CompareTo(y.depth));
```

On this way you sort the original array instead of creating new one.

Answer (score 10):

you find an example here: [How would I sort through an array of structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634017/how-would-i-sort-through-an-array-of-structs)

you have two ways to do this, compact or expanded way:

```
struct bla
{
    public string name;
    public float depth;
}

bla[] theArray = new bla[5];

Array.Sort(theArray, (x, y) => x.depth.CompareTo(y.depth));

Array.Sort(theArray, delegate(bla bla1, bla bla2)
{
    return bla1.depth.CompareTo(bla2.depth);
});
```

swap x or y or bla1 and bla2 if the sort order is opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 5):

using `System.Linq;`

```
blas.OrderByDescending(x=>x.depth)
```

or

```
Array.Sort(blas, (x, y) => y.depth.CompareTo(x.depth) );
```

Comment: Great, thanx, but would you give me an example with Array.sort?

Comment: With Array.Sort it looks very similar: Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => x.depth.CompareTo(y));

Comment: @CodesInChaos any reason to be rude?